# Classify the non-abelian subgroups of order 20.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$20=2^2\times5 $

My initial reaction was to write direct products between an abelian and non abelian groups — for example, $Z_5\times D_2$. However, I realized they are both abelian so I am a little stuck. I can't think of any subgroup that is not abelian. Could it be a semidirect product or something? If so, could you give me a hint? My knowledge of semidirect products is sketchy to say the least.

Comment: $D_4$ is not abelian

Comment: Pardon me I meant to write $D_2$ because $|D_2|$=4

Comment: then edit your question please.

Comment: One obvious one is the dihedral group of order 20, which is the semidirect product of $Z_5$ with $Z_2\times Z_2$. There ought to be a couple of semidirect products of $Z_5$ with $Z_4$ depending on whether the (nontrivial) map from $Z_4$ to Aut $Z_5$ is an isomorphism or maps to a subgroup of order 2.

Comment: To classify all nonabelian groups of order $20$, you should use the [Sylow Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).  What can you say about the number of Sylow $2$- and $5$-subgroups?

Answer (score 0):

take $D_5\times Z_2$. $D_5$ is non-abelian.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking you had to make subgroups only of 4 and 5 or 2,2 and 5, but I think you're right. Would this be the only one?

Comment: that I am not sure but ...every group of order $2,3,4,5$ is abelian